# DateTime Format Outputting Wrong Time

Tags: rest-api, datetime, string, c#

I am currently building an external web application using MVC. I need to format the DateTime to match Salesforce's format so I can push it up via API endpoints.

The DateTime picker in my View works just fine, it outputs the selected time in which the user inputs, then I am using a `.toString("s")` to format it into an acceptable form for the API.

**BUT**

after it gets converted, the variable I assign it to does not display the time selected, it just displays `00` (Keep in mind I'm talking in breakpoint speed).

It then gets pushed to Salesforce and the time is no where near what the user inputs.

**For Example**

the User would input 3:30 PM (The Date part works just fine, just the time part doesn't work) and when it gets pushed up to Salesforce, it would be 10:30AM .

Any ideas ?

Comment: Might be a timezone issue?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce stores all date-time values in UTC, but displays them in the user's time zone in the UI.

Almost any time you have an N-hour discrepancy between the time you expect and the time you see, it's because you used a local-time value when Salesforce expected UTC or vice versa. Here, it appears that your external application is accepting input in user-local time and then sending it to Salesforce without performing time-zone conversion.

Salesforce interprets this value as UTC, and then attempts to re-convert it to local time when displaying it. This results in an offset from the time value you expected.

Always convert date-times to UTC when sending them to Salesforce via the API, and interpret results from Salesforce APIs in UTC (unless explicitly stated to be in user-local timezone).

Comment: I have done a ``ToUniversalTime().ToString()`` before it hits the create method and it doesn't like this format either. Would you have any suggestions, code wise, about how to convert to UTC? I would imagine the datetime picker I am using that uses local time, would be able to get converted to UTC successfully, right?

Comment: @CodyB I am not a C# programmer so I'm afraid I do not have the domain knowledge to advise you there.

Comment: No problem, I'll try to figure it out based on the info you gave me, thank you

Comment: I figured it out, I had to Convert it to Universal Date time using AND THEN format it to the format they want. ``ToUniversalTime().ToString("s");``